# Can't create a Hive Table from an avro file

Tags: hive, create-table, avro

I can create a table atop an avro file using the following syntax without any errors. It is an empty table at firs.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE  tableName 
PARTITIONED BY (ingestiondatetime BIGINT, recordtype STRING)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serd2.avro.AvroSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
TABLEPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.url'='hdfs:///user/file.avsc');
```

When I add the LOCATION line to point to the actual avro file loctaion, I get a permission error

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE  tableName 
PARTITIONED BY (ingestiondatetime BIGINT, recordtype STRING)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serd2.avro.AvroSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
LOCATION '/local/avro_dir/'
TABLEPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.url'='hdfs:///user/file.avsc');
```

The error is

```
> FAILED:  Error in metadata.....  
> org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: 
> user=hive, access=WRITE, inode="/" hdfs:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
```

I am running hive as me.  My permissions on hdfs:/  are wide open (777).   Where is hive trying to write to that it thinks it does not have permission?

Comment: could you show the complete query with location added?

Answer (score 2):

It is trying to do this as the hive user.

Here is the error & what It is trying to tell you

**Permission denied: user=hive, access=WRITE, inode="/" hdfs:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x**

The exception tells you:
who it is doing it: **user=hive** 
what the user is trying to do:  **access=WRITE** 
what dire is being accessed:  **inode="/"**
the permissions of the location:
  **hdfs:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x**

> run hadoop fs -ls -la /

The permissions you describe (777) are not reflected in the error message. the permissions in the error message suggest that everyone has read & execute, but not write.

As Amar states, seeing the full command would be helpful!

If this were me, it would be because I had a typo in the location, and hive was trying to create the directory.

if you run 
`hadoop fs -ls [your LOCATION property ]`
.. does the location exist?

Best of luck!

Brian

Answer (score 0):

TABLEPROPERTIES should be TBLPROPERTIES

Also for those using an API, the ";" is not allowed, at least with my version of Spark and Hive, but you know how fast this changes.

Answer (score 0):

your current user is hive which dont have write permission for inode="/"

before starting hive from command prompt
try to change ur current user to hdfs by writing

export HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs